# Access error: can not add records joint key of table 'TableName' not in recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two linked Tables 'tblPatients' and 'tblDSA' and two continues forms 'frmPatients' and 'frmDSA'. When I create a new patient via 'frmPatient'I would like to add a new record for that patient in 'frmDSA' without closing the form.

On 'frmPatients' next to each record there is a button 'SaveNewRecord' that does the following:

(1)saves a new record to 'tblPatients' and also filters 
(2) opens 'frmDSA' to display related records to that Patients.

Here is the filtering code:

```
If Not Me.NewRecord Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "DSAfrm", _
        WhereCondition:="LABCODE=" & Me.LABCODE
End If
```

Here is what happens:

After the 'DSAfrm' pops up and I try to enter a new record I get the following error."can not add records joint key of table 'TableName' not in record-set"

The new patient has been save to 'tblPatients' but Access is not letting me add any new records. Please help!

Here is the code that I use to save the new records:

```
Private Sub Command385_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim PatientTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim DSAtable As DAO.Recordset2

Dim errMsg As String 'Where we will store error messages

Dim errData As Boolean 'Default = False   if we have an error we will set it to True.

Dim i As Integer 'used as a counter in For..Next loops.
Dim x As Integer 'used as counter in For..Next loops.

Dim errorArray(0 To 3) As String 'Array to hold the error messages so we can 'use them if needed.

If Me.LABCODE.Value = "" Then
            errorArray(0) = "Must Enter Labcode."
            errData = True
End If
If Me.LastName.Value = 0 Then
            errorArray(1) = "Must Enter Patient Number"
            errData = True
End If
If Me.FirstName.Value = "" Then
            errorArray(2) = "Must Enter Insurance Type"
            errData = True
End If
If Me.MRN.Value = "" Then
            errorArray(3) = "Must Enter Intake Nurse"
            errData = True
End If



'MsgBox "errData = " & errData
If errData = True Then
  i = 0
  x = 0
    For i = 0 To 3
        If errorArray(i) <> "" Then
            If x > 0 Then
            errMsg = errMsg & vbNewLine & errorArray(i)
            Else
            errMsg = errorArray(i)
            x = x + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox errMsg & vbNewLine & "Please try again."
    errMsg = ""
    Me.LABCODE.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set PatientTable = db.OpenRecordset("tblPatients")

    With PatientTable
        .AddNew
        !LABCODE = Me.LABCODE.Value
        !LastName = Me.LastName.Value
        !FirstName = Me.FirstName.Value
        !MRN = Me.MRN.Value
        !MRNTwo = Me.MRN2.Value
        Debug.Print Me.MRN.Value
        '!CPI#2 = Me.MRN2.Value
        !Kidney = Me.cbKidney.Value
        !Heart = Me.cbHeart.Value
        !Lung = Me.cbLung.Value
        !Liver = Me.cbLiver.Value
        !Pancreas = Me.cbPancreas.Value

        !DateLogged = Format(Date, "MM/DD/YY")
        .Update
    End With
'End If
  Set DSAtable = db.OpenRecordset("tblDSA")
        With DSAtable
            .AddNew
            !LABCODE = Me.LABCODE.Value
            .Update
        End With
'Let the user know it worked.
MsgBox "This patient has been added successfully.", vbOKOnly

 'If Not Me.NewRecord Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "DSAfrm", _
        WhereCondition:="LABCODE=" & Me.LABCODE
'End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where you refresh your recordset for 'frmPatients'. Is that form bound to the recordset 'tblPatients'? What is the recordsource for form 'frmDSA'  Take a look at the following link and see if that helps. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/cannot-add-record-join-key-of-table-is-not-in/9df69347-3303-4442-a1f6-b9302cddf4c2?auth=1

Comment: It sounds like every record in DSAfrm's recordsource has to have a matching ID in frmPatient's recordsource. Just by adding the WhereCondition when you open the form is not going to load the matching ID - you're going to have to set it when you load the form - perhaps by passing a parameter to the OpenForm command?

Comment: @Wayne, I need to refresh record set? The recordsource for form 'DSAfrm' is a query qryPatientDSA that joins both tables and contains all the fields.  Is that the problem? Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how to set ID when I load 'DSAfrm'?

Comment: If: (a) your query is joining both tables; and (b) the DSA record does not yet exist; and (c) you use an 'Inner Join', you will not have the desired record. A left join would allow you to 'see' the Patient in frmDSA, or possibly a better solution is to add code to your above sub to add a 'placeholder' DSA record?

Comment: I display information from tblPatients on 'DSAfrm'.. that is the reason for the joining both tables. Could you please suggest an example code that will solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Just before your line of code ''Let the user know it worked.' you can add code to save a DSA record with the required key. Thus when the next form is opened, it will have the TWO recquired records joined together.

Comment: After I added code that creates  a new  DSA records the button code above executes.  However, when I close frmDSA and navigate to frmPatient, Access tries to save the new patient twice for some reason.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254905/run-time-error-3022-duplicate-values?noredirect=1#comment63940373_38254905. I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks